# Creating a new object output 2 times the result

Tags: node.js, oop

Okay the question is when I "instanciate" a new object, and run a function from the object, it run 2 times, why's that ? Could some one explain me ?

Example:

server.js

```
var http = require("http");
var testObj = require("/path/to/obj");

exports.start = function() {

  function onRequest(request, response)
  {
        var app = new testObj();
        app.date();
        response.writeHead(200, {"Content-Type": "application/json"});
        response.write('Testing stuff!');
        response.end();
  }

  http.createServer(onRequest).listen(config.core.server_port);
  console.log("Server has started.");
};
```

obj.js

```
function Session(){

}

Session.prototype.date = function(){
       var date = new Date();
      console.log(date);
};

module.exports = Session;
```

The output in console should be only a date print, but I'm getting two dates prints, why is that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Most likely the browser is making another request for favicon.

Comment: Short and simple, It's a good point and it's plausible that is the browser requesting the favicon I'm going dump the request and see the url, if one of the requests matches the favicon, I select this answer as true.

Comment: You are right here is the output:
Fri Mar 14 2014 17:16:27 GMT+0000 (WET)
/
Fri Mar 14 2014 17:16:27 GMT+0000 (WET)
/favicon.ico